# Angularjs (1) types (ng.*) in compodoc are undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, compodoc

Can you help me with next problem. 
I have a class:

```
export class MyClass {
    public static $inject: string[] = [
        "$element",
        "$scope"
    ];
    constructor(
        private $element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, 
        private $scope: ng.IScope
    ) {}
}
```

and by Compodoc I had created documentation and got this:

> constructor(MyClass:  $element: undefined, $scope: undefined)

Can someone tell me how to fix the problem with incorrect types in documentation?